The variation of acid representation in mechanisms
Why sometimes in a mechanism are acids represented as physical acid molecules (alkene + conc sulfuric acid, conc sulfuric acid + conc nitric acid) and othertimes as H+ ions / Hydronium ions. (Alkene hydration, water acid catalyzed hydrolysis, alcohol dehydration) I thought it had to do with concentration - very concentrated acids start to have major amounts of actual acid molecules that aren't dissociated however sometimes (e.g in alcohol dehydration) even with concentrated acid, the H+ ion mechanism is used. Is it a mix of sumplicity and concentration

Not really. It is related with the mechanism of the reaction and the solution of the kinetic equations. Review your Physical Chemistry textbook on the section where it address "homogenous catalysis", "acid-base catalysis" "specific acid catalysis" or "general acid catalysis"

@PAEP more concentrated acids would have more undissociated acid molecules though right if acid molar ratio > water (e.g 98% H2SO4)? Similar question asked on stack exchange where this answer given by experienced people. And would it play even a slight part in this

Give examples related to the question

Note that the way of acid presentation in reaction schema need not to properly represent the actual reaction mechanism. It may be in many cases just the preference of the author.

Ohh ok so sometimes preference appeals over even if a certain chemical is actually doing the mechanism

A classic example is the hidrolysis of ethyl vinyl ether in auqueous solution which can suffer both specific and general acid catalysis. A. J. Kresge and Y. Chiang, The hydrolysis of ethyl vinyl ether. Part I. Reaction mechanism  J. Chem. Soc. B., 53–57, 58–61 (1967)

The way an acid is shown in a mechanism can indicate the presence or absence of water, or can distinguish between general or specific acid catalysis.
When the acid is shown as $\ce{H3O+}$, it indicates the presence of water. Some reactions, for example ester formation, benefit from the absence of water yet are acid catalyzed, so in those cases $\ce{H+}$ would be appropriate.
Some reactions in aqueous solution have a mechanism that directly involves $\ce{H3O+}$ (i .e. the protonated solvent, specific acid catalysis). In that case, showing the hydronium ion would be appropriate. Other mechanisms work with any acid (e.g. the protonated species of a buffer, present at much higher concentration than hydronium). For these cases, it might be appropriate to state the acid as $\ce{HA}$.
If you are describing a reaction that always uses the same acid, then you would just put that one in the mechanism.

So concentration is a partial but not complete factor. Other factors like catalysation and medium are important

@Fritzy123 I think catalization does not exist. The reaction may be catalysed or not. Of course in solution the the solvent is pretty important and, if the concentrations are very high, the ionic strength. In many reaction the solvent takes part in the reaction.

@PAEP For some mechanisms with conc acid, some people use whole acid molecules while for same mechanism, others use H+ (e.g alcohol dehydration). But physically, the composition of concentrated acid (98% H2SO4) is undissociated acid molecules. So mechanism with acid molecules should be correct. Is it for simplicity because there is no water here. Same for e.g esterification.

@Fritzy123 A 98% $\ce{H2SO4}$ is not an an aqueous solution of sulphuric acid in water. The solvent is  sulphuric acid. It is a different beast.
